# Match words from 2 files

Tags: javascript, bash, parsing, text-processing

I have 2 txt file's (words.txt and fail.txt)

words.txt

```
level4:the
level4:of
level4:and
level4:to
level4:a
level4:in
level4:for
level4:is
level4:on
level4:that
level4:by
level4:this
level4:with
level4:i
level4:you
```

fail.txt

```
the
of
and
to
a
in
```

How can I obtain a list that will contain all the list from words.txt except those from fail.txt? 
EXAMPLE of what i need to obtain as a result

```
level4:for
level4:is
level4:on
level4:that
level4:by
level4:this
level4:with
level4:i
level4:you
```

Thank you.

Comment: You have both Javascript and Bash tags. Which one do you want to use for parsing this?

Comment: @MikeC It dosent metter, witch one will solve this problem faster and easer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk -F: 'FNR==NR{fail[$0]++; next} !($2 in fail)' fail.txt words.txt
level4:for
level4:is
level4:on
level4:that
level4:by
level4:this
level4:with
level4:i
level4:you
```

**Description:**

```
-F :                         # use : as delimiter
NR == FNR {                  # While processing the fail file
  fail[$0]++                 # store the record in an array fail
  next                       # move to next record
}
{                            # while processing the words file
  !($2 in fail)              # print if 2nd field is not in fail array
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can I save the result in .txt file>?

Comment: Yes `awk -F: 'FNR==NR{fail[$0]++; next} !($2 in fail)' fail.txt words.txt > output.txt`